# Different ways to update a react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

I will be pushing a react-native app to App Store and play store. Since the product is still under dev (beta right now) I would like to push the app updates to users. I am aware that codepush will help me push js changes but are there ways where user can perform an in app updates for binary (.app file) when the app is published on different stores.

Comment: From what I understood from your question. You want to release native changes to your users when the app is published. The only way to do so is by uploading your release apk/ipa to stores. Codepush only helps in JS changes.

Comment: is there a way that the install automatically starts without redirecting the users to the stores?

Comment: Only JS changes can be automatically installed with codepush. For all native changes you will have to go via stores. Your users should go to the store.

Comment: If you are worried they may not, then you can use codepush to push a banner on existing app asking them to go to store to download and continue using.